# Regex to replace bracket notation with dot notation - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working with a compiler that will take in only dot notations(including arrays). For example, for the object below:

```js
 var defaults = {
     'background-color': '#000',
     color: '#fff',
     tokens: [{token: '3der3ergfg44effg'},{token: '3dertkyohlhjeffg'},[
            {tokenNest: 'sgvchjjd3fe5yd522s'},
            {boomer: [33]}]]
    };

    console.log(defaults.tokens[2])
    console.log(defaults.tokens[2][0])
    console.log(defaults.tokens[2][1].boomer[0])
```

The way my compiler expects the path is in dot notation

For example `defaults.tokens[2]` should be `defaults.tokens.2` and `defaults.tokens[2][0]` should be `defaults.tokens.2.0`

If I want to access number 33, the path I will have to pass is `defaults.tokens.2.1.boomer.0` instead of `defaults.tokens[2][1].boomer[0]`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I'm working with a compiler that will take in only dot notations(including arrays). " — so **not** a JavaScript compiler then. Why is this tagged [tag:javascript]?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ehh ...Shouldn't you rather need a regexp replacing dot notation to bracket notation?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to change your square brackets syntax to dot syntax, so like this: `\[(\d+)\]` replace with `.$1`? https://regex101.com/r/5IZTFi/1

Comment: @Quentin because path is a JS string, and the language used here is JS.

Comment: @Teemu No, I think I framed it right

Comment: @ctwheels Yes, that is what I'm looking for. How do I write it in Javascript?

Comment: Are you compiling your "own language" to JS or vice versa? I mean in JS accessing a number as a key is a syntax error when using dot notation.

Comment: @FooBar144 click on the link and click "code generator" on the left and select JavaScript.

Comment: I need to process a JS string, which is for example `defaults.tokens[2][1].boomer[0]` to `defaults.tokens.2.1.boomer.0`. Sorry for bad english

Comment: OHHHHHH It sure sounded like you were doing it the other way around. I will change my answer.

Comment: @ctwheels Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this with a regex, because square brackets may appear in comments, string literals, and are even used for array literals in addition to object property references.

I see that you clarified the question in a comment.

It appears you want to take in JavaScript code and replace bracketed property access with dotted access. Here is how to do it.

Get [Esprima](http://esprima.org/) and use it to parse your JavaScript code. This will give you an abstract syntax tree for JavaScript. Navigate that tree, outputting text in whatever your language is called. Most everything will pass through untouched, but whenever you see property access, you will write out dotted notation.

But beware! This process sounds like a terrible idea!

What if you had JavaScript that looked like this?

```
myObject["x; eraseMyData();"]
```

It would turn into

```
myObject.x; eraseMyData();
```

I think you might want to abandon this project. JavaScript uses bracketed notation for a very good reason!